# Raspberry Pi Pico accurate sunrise time

Tags: python, pi-pico, micropython

Is there a way to access or calculate sunrise and sunset times according to latitude and longitude with a raspberry pi pico ? I can do it with my raspberry pi 3b+ and astral but astral doesnt seem to work with the pico. I dont need the latitude or longitude specifically, I just need a method to set an accurate location.